# which class or method to use from windows forms namespace to show the name of running script using powershell in a form class

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

I have a powershell script which calls for a progress bar in a form showing execution of some batch files. Which class or method should be used from windows forms namespace to show the name of running batch script using powershell in a form class.
In the code below, in installationScriptsHome folder there are bunch of batch and vbs files, while those scripts are being called i want to show the name of the running script over the progress bar to show which script is running or may be some customised name\message with each script.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
$ScriptsHome = Get-Item 'c:\installationScriptsHome\*'

# Init Form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 1000
$Form.height = 200
$Form.Text = "**OSP Installation in Progress**"

# Init ProgressBar
$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar.Maximum = $ScriptsHome.Count
$ProgressBar.Minimum = 0
$ProgressBar.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,70)
$ProgressBar.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(967,10)
$Form.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)

# Add_Shown action    
$ShownFormAction = {
    $Form.Activate()

    foreach ($b in $ScriptsHome) {
        $ProgressBar.Increment(1)
        Start-Process $b.FullName -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
    }
    $Form.Dispose()
}
$Form.Add_Shown($ShownFormAction)

# Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. Do you mean the form header, which you've set using `$Form.Text`? Or another area in the form? Screenshots and paint would be helpful.

Comment: @Gmsoulman- $form.text is showing a static text on the header of the progress bar for which it is intended. I want to add a dynamic text just above the progress bar animation showing which backend script is currently running for eg:- "stopping xxxxx services, abc process might get affected". This kind of interactive messages will be for the end user.

Comment: Thanks, answered, let me know if unclear

Comment: @Gmsoulman-thanks it worked with a slight modification by adding $Form.Controls.Add($Label) just below $Label.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)

Comment: Apologies, I should have included that. Basically New-Object sets up the form item, but you do have to add it to the form afterwards as you have done for `$ProgressBar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Label` class ([MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
$Label          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(140,20) 
$Label.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)

# put this in the foreach ($b in $ScriptsHome) { loop
$Label.Text     = "$($b.Name)"
```

Useful link: [MSDN System.Windows.Forms NameSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms(v=vs.110).aspx)